# Lie groups with structure constant $f_{abc} \neq f_{bca}$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness, simple-groups

The structure constant $f_{abc}$ of Lie group is defined by the commutators of generators,

$$[T^a,T^b]=i f_{abc}T_c$$

automatically $f_{abc}=-f_{bac}$.

Can someone give **a list of explicit examples of Lie groups** such that the structure constant with the property:

$$f_{abc} \neq f_{bca}$$

(i.e. not cyclic.)

**The more examples the better.** Thank you.

---

(ps.**For $f_{abc} =f_{bca}$, the Lie group has to be compact semi-simple(?)**.)

Comment: The question has to be rephrased: if $f_{abc}= f_{bca}$ is satisfied, then changing the basis $T^a$ to $2T^a$ for some $a$, you will have $ f_{abc}\neq  f_{bca}$.

Comment: I was looking for nontrivial examples (i.e. NOT compact semi-simple Lie group.)